# Is there a way to show list of all open sockets on a Windows server and the socket properties?

Tags: windows-7, socket

We are using a third party library in one of our applications. We would like to find a tool which will list all of the open sockets on the machine AND give us the ability to see the various TCP properties associated with the socket suck as:
SendBufferSize
ReceiveBufferSize
NoDelay (Nagle)
DontFragment
TTL

We've spoken to the vendor, and although they have disabled Nagle on their server, we would like to know exactly how the sockets are being created with their library on our servers.

Any tools out there for this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a solution for you, but i read this post where they use Wireshark/Netmon to show/monitor delays in TCP packets to detect whether Nagle is used or not:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/06/25/nagle-s-algorithm-is-not-friendly-towards-small-requests.aspx

(i'm not allowed to post comments so had to put this in an answer..)